# Leaflet map click event: how to update bar plot in external div?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, json, chart

I made this code to trigger a graph every time you click on a GeoJSON feature, so that for each polygon in the map, the graph shows data for the corresponding name of the region ("Comune"). The data is contained in a variable called myJSON.

Example:

```
var myJSON = [{

"": 0,
"Comune": "BONDENO",
"PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1516": 4.25,
"Value 1": 63,
"Value 2": 8,
"Value 3": 17,
"DANNO": 6,
"Somma valori": 88,
"numero_di_scuole": 4,
"CERTIFICATOAGIBILITAABITABILITA": "",
"DOCUMENTOVALUTAZIONERISCHIO": "",
"PIANOEMERGENZA": "",
"PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1617": 5.5,
"VINCOLIPAESAGGIO": 1,
"EDIFICIOVETUSTO": 0,
"PROGETTAZIONEANTISISMICA": 1,
"VINCOLIIDROGEOLOGICI": 0,
"PUNTEGGIO_SCUOLE_PARITARIE_1516": "",
"PUNTEGGIO_SCUOLE_PARITARIE_1617": ""]}
```

When I click on "BONDENO" on the map, the bar plot should show "Value1" and "Value2". However, I can't get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
function geo_json_dc64d985f99647e7b35676bc82a64cc7_onEachFeature(
  feature,
  layer
) {
  layer.on({
    mouseout: function(e) {
      geo_json_dc64d985f99647e7b35676bc82a64cc7.resetStyle(e.target);
    },
    mouseover: function(e) {
      e.target.setStyle(
        geo_json_dc64d985f99647e7b35676bc82a64cc7_highlighter(e.target.feature)
      );
    },
    click: function(e) {
      map_ae26379126cd4ce79aea9d0f395ec09f.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());

      myJSON.forEach(function(arrayItem) {
        if (
          arrayItem["Comune"] ==
          e.target.feature.properties.NOME_COM.toUpperCase()
        ) {
          $("#welcome").remove();
          $("#information").html("");
          $("#information").html(
            '<div class="card alert-success mb-3"> <h3 class="card-header">Zona ' +
              arrayItem.Comune +
              '</h3> <div class="card-body text-right pb-0"> <ul style="list-style-type:none"> <li><h6> punteggioscuole: ' +
              arrayItem.PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1516
          );
          $("#chartContainer").append(
            '<canvas id="redditiChart" width="200" height="200"><canvas>'
          );
          var grafobase = document
            .getElementById("redditiChart")
            .getContext("2d");

          new Chart(grafobase, {
            type: "bar",
            data: {
              datasets: [
                {
                  label: ?,
                  data: ?,
                  backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
                  borderWidth: 1
                }
              ]
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

How can I do that? You can see how my code currently works [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/s113MZmE5mbaJAs6rM7P?p=preview).

Comment: What does this `Chart` object come from? Without knowing it's parameter specs it's impossible to answer.

Comment: it's chart.js! An attempt, at least

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be an attempt to guess of how you would want your chart to look like.

Option `labels` gives label to each of your data on x axis, option `label` names your data set (displayed above chart), option `data` within `datasets` option sets your data values. Option `scales` set the range of data values on y axis.

So you `Chart` definition could look something like:

```
new Chart(grafobase, {
  type: 'bar',
  options: {scales: {yAxes: [{ticks: {suggestedMin: 0, suggestedMax: 100 }}]}},
  data:{
    labels: ['Value 1', 'Value2'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Test',
        data: [arrayItem['Value 1'], arrayItem['Value 2']],
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
  }
}
```

Since this is not really GIS question but pure HTML one, if you have any additional question, you'll have to ask on StackExchange.

Comment: It was what I needed! Thank you.